# Scrollview Realigns textView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a blank activity which contains many text view so I want to use scrollview but whenever I use it the text views shift from their preassigned position to the top.[Before adding ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCV9O.png) and
[After adding ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M1S1.png) here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="torchToggle"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:background="#cdc6c6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Torch"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#e8d9d9" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#dacece"
    android:text="#Error In display" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:textColor="#cdc0c0"
    android:text="#Error in display" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textColor="#f3ef7a"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="#Error in display" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="next"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:onClick="nextActivity" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of your `RelativeLayout` is falling back to `wrap_content` when inside the `ScrollView` as the virtual height of the `ScrollView` is infinite and `match_parent` doesn't make sense.

You could try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView`. This will give the `RelativeLayout` a minimum height of `match_parent`. You should change the `RelativeLayout`'s `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.